# Vim: toggle highlighting of long lines

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, vim-syntax-highlighting

In my .vimrc, I have:

```
:au BufWinEnter * let w:m1=matchadd('Search', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
```

to highlight lines that stray over the 80 character limit. How can I set it so that this is toggled on/off by pressing a function key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use mappings.

To activate highlight:

```
:nnoremap <leader>1 :match Search '\%>80v.\+'<CR>
```

To deactivate it:

```
:nnoremap <leader>2 :match none<CR>
```

---

**UPDATE** to use same key/key combination to toggle highlight:

```
let s:activatedh = 0 
function! ToggleH()
    if s:activatedh == 0
        let s:activatedh = 1 
        match Search '\%>80v.\+'
    else
        let s:activatedh = 0 
        match none
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>1 :call ToggleH()<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I bind it to a key exactly?

Comment: @AlexJ136: `<leader>1` is a key combination. Use whatever you want.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to toggle it using a single key?

Comment: @AlexJ136: Just updated when posted [ebenezer's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/758011/ebenezer) link. Use whatever fits best for you. I tested this one and seems to work.