# how to easily toggle 'match' to be on or off?

Tags: vim

I have some customization in my `.vimrc` to highlight text that is over 80 characters wide:

```
" highlight text over 80 columns wide
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

This can get in the way sometimes, so ideally I would like to be able to quickly toggle this behavior on or off with just a few keys.  How can I do this in `vim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was already answered thoroughly in [Vim: toggle highlighting of long lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594119/vim-toggle-highlighting-of-long-lines) which walks you through using `map` to do this.